# How to specify ANY string

Tags: python-3.x

So I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
import re
master = Tk()
e1 = Entry(master)
def confirmit():
    s = re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', e1.get())
    if e1.get() == "Whoscreator":
        vyvod.configure(text="Kewbin")
    if e1.get() == "Whatscreatorsrealname":
         vyvod.configure(text="Peťo Letec")
    if e1.get() == "/give " + (what should I type here?):
        vyvod.configure(text= s)
vyvod = Label(master, text="First Name")
confirmer = Button(text="Confirm", command = confirmit)
e1.pack()
vyvod.pack()
confirmer.pack()
mainloop()
```

I have an entry bar. 
And I want this for example:
If I type in the bar `/give 1000` it will type the number `1000` into Label vyvod. And I want this to work with any number i type after `/give`

Comment: Since you want to check that `e1.get()` starts with `"/give "`, you can use `e1.get().startswith("/give ")`.

Or you could modify your regex to find both the number and the command and check that the latter is "/give"

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to split the string on a space, examine the first word, and do whatever is appropriate with the rest.

```
value = e1.get()
first, rest = value.split(" ", 1)
if first == "/give":
    vyvod.configure(text=rest)
```